# Natural Numbers Sum of Digits using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

Im trying to implement a function that returns a natural number which is the sum of the digits within an entered natural number. I just keep on getting an infinite loop. I know i have to return the recursive call but i cant figure this out. Here is what i have so far:

```
private static NaturalNumber sumOfDigits(NaturalNumber n) {
        NaturalNumber zero = new NaturalNumber2(0);
        if (n.compareTo(zero) == 0) {
            return zero;
        } else {
            NaturalNumber z = new NaturalNumber2(n.divideBy10());
            n.divideBy10();
            z.add(sumOfDigits(n));

         // return ___;

        }
    }
```

What am i supposed to return? Returning z doesn't work

Comment: What do you need the NaturalNumber class for?

Comment: We're just recursing away like topsy today, aren't we?  I'd suggest you review one of the 4-5 other threads started in the last 24 hours discussing basic recursion -- the same principles apply.

Comment: @Cruncher - It makes it more complicated.

Comment: @HotLicks `divideBy10` is my new favourite method

Comment: @HotLicks Ive reviewed it and i have implemented this returning and int instead of a NN and it works. Im just trying to figure out how to return ``z.add(sumOfDigits(n));`` but it gives me a void error

Comment: (Do keep in mind that if you know about SO your professor knows about it too and likely will detect if you simply copy an answer given to you.  So be sure to do your own work (or at least obfuscate it well).)

Comment: `NaturalNumber2` ?? I bet you miss some basic piece of OO understanding

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D or NaturalNumberIntenalOps. I came here for help not to get bashed on my knowledge

Comment: @WestonBuckeye: I insist you miss some _basic piece of OO understanding_ and this is _help_. Moreover when you post a question with classes _you_ created you should post the code of those classes.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D I didnt create any classes, this is just a question to implement and assume.

Comment: ? is NaturalNumber2 a standard library class ?

Comment: Does the NaturalNubmer2 add method return the result of the addition? or does it change the state of the object it is being called on and return void?  If it returns void then you would have to call the add and then just return the object separately.

Answer (score 1):

You are making the recursive call with n, the same number that was passed into your procedure.  If you strip off a digit for z, then the recursive call has to be made with the rest of the digits.

You can strip off a digit with mod 10 and then get the rest of the digits by divide by 10.  If you were using ints it would be:

```
return (n % 10) + sumOfDigits(n / 10);
```

Comment: That is exactly how i have it when i created this for an int. Here i have to return a NaturalNumber and it does not let me return ``z.add(sumOfDigits(n));``

Comment: What does z.add return?  Does it return the result of the add or does it mutate the state of z and return void?

Answer (score 0):

`z.add(sumOfDigits(n));` should be `z.add(sumOfDigits(n.divideBy10()));`.  The main point is in the recursion you only want to process the remainder of the answer, not the whole problem.

Comment: ``n.divideBy10()`` gives me the digit i need to add. If do the recursion having that one single digit, its going to divide it by 10. Not what i want here

Comment: @WestonBuckeye Does it? What's `5463/10` ? it's not `5` or `3`. I think you're looking for `n % 10`.

Comment: @Cruncher ok, i fixed that mix up, but what do i need to return?

Comment: @Cruncher If i input 223456. My NN z that i have on the top is equal to 6. n.divideBy10() gives back a remainder